# Ubuntu is suddenly not detecting second monitor anymore, probably Nvidia issue

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, hdmi, external-monitor

I have Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS running, and all of a sudden my laptop won't recognize my second monitor anymore via HDMI. I tried hooking it up via usb-c port, which also did not work. I have a separate usb-c port on the side of the laptop, and there it does work for some reason.

Searching the other threads I figured it was most likely an Nvidia driver issue, but trying the suggested answers did not help for me.

I tried changing the driver version (both 545, 535, 525 and 470 do not work), as well as:

```
sudo apt-get purge 'nvidia*'
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

which also did not work. Is there anything else I can try?